# Emit one List item at a time from a Flowable

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a method which returns a `Flowable<RealmResults<MyClass>>`. For those not familiar with Realm, `RealmResults` is just a simple `List` of items.

Given a `Flowable<RealmResults<MyClass>>`, I'd like to emit each `MyClass` item so that I can perform a `map()` operation on each item.

I am looking for something like the following:

```
getItems() // returns a Flowable<RealmResults<MyClass>>
    .emitOneAtATime() // Example operator
    .map(obj -> obj + "")
    // etc
```

What operator will emit each List item sequentially?

Comment: Is something like blockingNext() be applicable? It returns an iterable and blocks until the next emit.

Answer (score 16):

You would `flatMap(aList -> Flowable.fromIterable(aList))`.  Then you can `map()` on each individual item.  There is `toList()` if you want to recollect the items (note: this would be a new List instance).  Here's an example illustrating how you can use these methods to get the different types using `List<Integer>`.

```
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
Flowable<Integer> intergerListFlowable = 
            Flowable
                    .just(integerList)//emits the list
                    .flatMap(list -> Flowable.fromIterable(list))//emits one by one
                    .map(integer -> integer + 1);
```

Comment: `flatMapIterable(list -> list)` is a bit nicer though admittedly you could just write `flatMap(Flowable::fromIterable)`

Comment: It will work perfectly fine in this case, but I'm not a fan of `flatMapIterable` for these scenarios.  Based on the documentation for that method it seems that the intended use case involves combinations.  


http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html  "*The flatMapIterable variants pair up source items and generated Iterables rather than source items and generated Observables*"  Also note the marble diagram in which emitted items are not necessarily returned in serial order.

Also didn't use method reference to be intentionally verbose for the example.

Answer (score 3):

The question is, do you want to keep the results as a `Flowable<List<MyClass>>` or as a `Flowable<MyClass>` with retained order?

If the first,

```
getItems()
.concatMap(results -> Flowable
   .fromIterable(results)
   .map(/* do your mapping */)
   .toList()
)
```

If the second, this should suffice:

```
getItems()
.concatMap(Flowable::fromIterable)
.map(/* do your mapping */)
```

Comment: what is results here?

Comment: @PrajwalW `results` in line 3 is defined in line 2.

Comment: what should i add in map() can u give an example pls?

Comment: I got a problem: I want to show my Flowable query select * statement data on a textview do u have an idea of this?

Comment: That should be a question on its own; make sure to attach enough context to it.

Comment: Here u go: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60587478/9166855 can u pls look into this!