# How to display Flowable data on a Textview in Room Database using Rxjava2

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, android-room

**DAO.class:**

```
@Dao
public interface VisitorDAO {

    @Query("Select * from visitor")
    Flowable<List<Visitor>> getAll();

    @Insert
    Completable Insert(Visitor visitor);    //Using Single or Maybe tells the Database and the mainthread that this operation will be performed on Rxjava.

    @Update
    public void Update(Visitor visitor);

    @Delete
    public void Delete(Visitor visitor);

}
```

**Code:**

```
   @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    visitorFlowable = database.visitorDAO().getAll();
                    t.setText(visitorFlowable.); //is this the right way????
                    Toast.makeText(Add_Visitors.this, "Insert Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I have set the Query as Flowable and the idea is to access those Flowable return type data and display it on a textview.

Answer (score 0):

`visitorFlowable = database.visitorDAO().getAll();`

will return a flowable, you need to subscribe it on UI Thread and update textView

```
database.visitorDAO().getAll()
                .observeOn(schedulerProviders.ui())
                .subscribe(
                    list -> {
                        //list is List<Visitor>, use it to update textView
                    },
                    throwable -> {
                        //this block is executed if any exception is thrown
                    }
            );
```